# Вопросы о data mining, machine learning, data science?

Tags: обсуждение, тематика

Можно ли задавать в вопросы на ru.stackoverflow.com о data mining, машинном обучении, data science?

Согласно википедии data science так вообще раздел информатики, но многие вопросы связанные с этими науками находятся на стыке областей, затрагивающих как алгоритмы так и математику, статистику, логику. Причем задать вопрос **только** (цитата из правил)

> ...относящийся:
>       к конкретной задаче программирования - коду, алгоритмам, реализации алгоритмов на определенных языках программирования;

достаточно проблематично, т.к эти науки находятся в смежных областях. 
Темы достаточно интересные, а уж на русском информации об этом мало, хотелось бы внести вклад в развитие.

Comment: А вы можете предложить пример вопроса и ответа? Вообще тема интересная.

Comment: ну вот например, насчет ошибок измерений, http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/479508/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%83%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BE%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9

Comment: По тегу R половина вопросов как раз не столько о программировании, сколько о статистике и data science: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/r

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Можно. Интересно же. И вроде было несколько подобных вопросов.