# Закрытие вопроса за создание одинаковых вопросов на разных сайтах сети

Tags: обсуждение, модерация, тематика, причины-закрытия

Наткнулся случайно на вопрос [Какой алгоритм регрессии выбрать для шумных (разбросанных) данных?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/486133/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BC-%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D1%88%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85). Он **"закрыт по причине того, что не по теме"**.

Во-первых, вопрос о том, является ли машинное обучение онтопиком [поднимался](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2237/%D0%92%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%8B-%D0%BE-data-mining-machine-learning-data-science) некоторое время назад. Обсуждение было не очень активное, но ответа про закрытие такой темы даже не поступало.

Во-вторых, есть ощущение, что закрыт он не из-за того, что он офтопик, а из-за этого [комментария](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/486133/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BC-%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D1%88%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85#comment728090_486133) участника англоязычного сообщества:

> Cross-posted on Stats.SE, Stack Overflow, SO.RU, and DataScience.SE: stats.stackexchange.com/q/188291/2921, stackoverflow.com/q/34474767/781723, ru.stackoverflow.com/q/486133, datascience.stackexchange.com/q/9529/8560. Please do not post the same question on multiple sites. Each community should have an honest shot at answering without anybody's time being wasted.

Ниже можно видеть [комментарий модератора](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/486133/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BC-%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D1%88%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85#comment728618_486133):

> Одновременное размещение вопроса на нескольких сайтах сети не допускается.

Вероятно, этот комментарий устарел, так как сейчас как раз активно развивается вопрос [ассоциации](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2983/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BC-%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%81-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B3-%D0%BA-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B5-%D1%81-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%89%D1%8C%D1%8E-%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2) одинаковых или похожих вопросов с других сайтов сети.

Я согласен, что бездумно копировать вопрос на все сайты сети не стоит (видимо, не стоило публиковать его на stats.SO и на SO), но на ruSO он смотрится вполне приемлемо.

*Дополнительно:*
Есть ли другие вопросы, закрытые с такой же формулировкой?

Comment: А у меня ощущение, что подобные вопросы закрываются из-за причины -- "надо же, понятия не имею, как на это можно ответить..."

Comment: _Есть ли другие вопросы, закрытые с такой же формулировкой?_ - примерно в то же время, с _таким же_ комментарием была попытка закрыть еще несколько вопросов, но там иностранному модератору писали, что _переводы - хорошо_. Возможно @Nick что-то не так понял

Comment: @Grundy да, возможно такое.

Comment: Переоткрыл, т.к. мы с остальными сайтами слабо пересекаемся по целевой аудитории.

Comment: Надо бы вынести ML на голосование.